# Get signal names from numbers in Python

Tags: python, signals

Is there a way to map a signal number (e.g. signal.SIGINT) to its respective name (i.e. "SIGINT")?

I'd like to be able to print the name of a signal in the log when I receive it, however I cannot find a map from signal numbers to names in Python, i.e.:

```
import signal
def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    logging.debug("Received signal (%s)" % sig_names[signum])

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
```

For some dictionary sig_names, so when the process receives SIGINT it prints:

```
Received signal (SIGINT)
```

Answer (score 131, accepted):

With the addition of the [`signal.Signals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.IntEnum) in Python 3.5 this is now as easy as:

```
>>> import signal
>>> signal.SIGINT.name
'SIGINT'
>>> signal.SIGINT.value
2
>>> signal.Signals(2).name
'SIGINT'
>>> signal.Signals['SIGINT'].value
2
```

Comment: pylint-3.7 gives me this: `E1101: Module 'signal' has no 'Signals' member (no-member)`. Why does this happen? Doesn't pylint "see" the enum?

Comment: @Paal: It's `(signal_number)` ,e.g.: `signal.Signals(2).name`not square brackets.

Comment: @cfi I'm not sure I follow. I found out that my comment was related to a pylint issue https://github.com/PyCQA/astroid/pull/1172

Comment: @Paal: Never mind. In my case I got the exact same pylint message because I mistyped the `.name` attribute access using `signal.Signals[2].name` when it should rather be `signal.Signals(2).name`. For me there was no pylint issue, but a user issue. My previous comment lacks context. I do apologize.

Answer (score 35):

There is none, but if you don't mind a little hack, you can generate it like this:

```
import signal
dict((k, v) for v, k in reversed(sorted(signal.__dict__.items()))
     if v.startswith('SIG') and not v.startswith('SIG_'))
```

Comment: Strictly speaking this will map 1 to `SIG_IGN` and `SIGHUP` on most platforms, so I suppose the test should be if `v.startswith('SIG') and not v.startswith('SIG_')`.

Comment: It also double-maps 6 to `SIGABRT` and `SIGIOT` on Mac OS X (though they could be used interchangeably, I suppose, unlike `SIG_IGN` - which isn't a signal).

Comment: @Brian: very true... it's not a perfect solution by far. But it's atleast somewhat platform independent.

Comment: No need to sort. The dict will store as it sees fit anyway.

Comment: @tbc0: the sort is to give a consistent list of signals since there are duplicates in the list, so it's most certainly needed

Comment: @Wolph not strictly needed, but I concede your point about consistency.

Comment: @JohnGreene I've just tested the code in both Python 3.8 and Python 3.9 and it works without an issue here. What isn't working for you?

Comment: Down-voting this, not because the answer is bad at the time it was written, but it is now very out of date. All supported versions of python support [using the Signals enum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35996948/453851).

Answer (score 12):

The Python Standard Library By Example shows this function in the chapter on signals:

```
SIGNALS_TO_NAMES_DICT = dict((getattr(signal, n), n) \
    for n in dir(signal) if n.startswith('SIG') and '_' not in n )
```

You can then use it like this:

```
print "Terminated by signal %s" % SIGNALS_TO_NAMES_DICT[signal_number]
```

Comment: or (perhaps slightly more preferable) `SIGNALS_TO_NAMES_DICT.get(signal_number, "Unnamed signal: %d" % signal_number)`

Comment: As @Wolph points out in his answer, this solution doesn't guarantee a consistent name to duplicate signals.

Answer (score 12):

As of Python 3.8, you can now use the [signal.strsignal()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.strsignal) method to return a textual description of the signal:

```python
>>> signal.strsignal(signal.SIGTERM)
'Terminated'

>>> signal.strsignal(signal.SIGKILL)
'Killed'
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this article when I was in the same situation and figured the handler is only handling one signal at a time, so I don't even need a whole dictionary, just the name of one signal:

```
sig_name = tuple((v) for v, k in signal.__dict__.iteritems() if k == signum)[0]
```

there's probably a notation that doesn't need the tuple(...)[0] bit, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: signame = [v for v, k in signal.__dict__.iteritems() if k == signum][0] works fine.

Comment: "signame = next(v for v, k in signal.__dict__.iteritems() if k == signum)" stops when it finds it instead of continuing through the rest of the dict (also, it doesn't have the [0] that @ssc didn't like :D).

Comment: If v, k are supposed to stand for keys and values, then the names should be reversed, e.g.

 sig_name = tuple((k) for k, v in signal.__dict__.iteritems() if v == signum)[0]

But then there are other values in signal's dict whose value may match v, in which case, depending on the order iteritems() returns items, you may print a nonsense name.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `help(signal)` says at the bottom:

```
DATA
    NSIG = 23
    SIGABRT = 22
    SIGBREAK = 21
    SIGFPE = 8
    SIGILL = 4
    SIGINT = 2
    SIGSEGV = 11
    SIGTERM = 15
    SIG_DFL = 0
    SIG_IGN = 1
```

So this should work:

```
sig_names = {23:"NSIG", 22:"SIGABRT", 21:"SIGBREAK", 8:"SIGFPE", 4:"SIGILL",
             2:"SIGINT", 11:"SIGSEGV", 15:"SIGTERM", 0:"SIG_DFL", 1:"SIG_IGN"}
```

Comment: Unfortunately different platforms have different signal numbers, so this isn't portable. Thanks, though.

Comment: For example, here's the Mac OS X `help(signal)`:     SIGABRT = 6
    SIGALRM = 14
    SIGBUS = 10
    SIGCHLD = 20
    SIGCONT = 19
    SIGEMT = 7
    SIGFPE = 8
    SIGHUP = 1
    SIGILL = 4
    SIGINFO = 29
    SIGINT = 2
    SIGIO = 23
    SIGIOT = 6
    SIGKILL = 9
    SIGPIPE = 13
    SIGPROF = 27
    SIGQUIT = 3
    SIGSEGV = 11
    SIGSTOP = 17
    SIGSYS = 12
    SIGTERM = 15
    SIGTRAP = 5
    SIGTSTP = 18
    SIGTTIN = 21
    SIGTTOU = 22
    SIGURG = 16
    SIGUSR1 = 30
    SIGUSR2 = 31
    SIGVTALRM = 26
    SIGWINCH = 28
    SIGXCPU = 24
    SIGXFSZ = 25

Comment: Ah - I really should have realized that, all things considered, especially since I've experienced how much different signals are on Windows and Linux. WoLpH's solution is cleaner anyway :)

Comment: I wouldn't say my solution is cleaner. Yes, it works on every platform but if your solution is an option, than I'd definately use it and use my version as a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35996948/2957469):

```
import signal

if hasattr(signal, "Signals"):
    def _signal_name(signum):
        try:
            return signal.Signals(signum).name
        except ValueError:
            pass
else:
    def _signal_name(signum):
        for n, v in sorted(signal.__dict__.items()):
            if v != signum:
                continue
            if n.startswith("SIG") and not n.startswith("SIG_"):
                return n

def signal_name(signum):
    if signal.SIGRTMIN <= signum <= signal.SIGRTMAX:
        return "SIGRTMIN+{}".format(signum - signal.SIGRTMIN)
    x = _signal_name(signum)
    if x is None:
        # raise ValueError for invalid signals
        signal.getsignal(signum)
        x = "<signal {}>".format(signum)
    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

for `signal_value` of positive number (signal number), or negative value (return status from subprocess):

```
import signal

signal_name = {
        getattr(signal, _signame): _signame
        for _signame in dir(signal)
        if _signame.startswith('SIG')
    }.get(abs(signal_value), 'Unknown')
```